# 18.04 Clamav virus definitions don't install after a new install of Ubuntu

Tags: clamav, clamtk

After installing Ubuntu 18.04 to its own drive on a dual booting high performance system (also Windows 10), I attempted to use [Clamtk](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/clamtk.1.html) ([home page](https://gitlab.com/dave_m/clamtk/-/wikis/Home)) to scan drives.  The result was an instant report of nothing found.  Clamav and Clamtk were installed from the Ubuntu repository

I then attempted virus signatures update and saw there were no virus definitions installed.  The download proceeded normally but there were still no virus signatures.

I then uninstalled Clamtk and used terminal to initiate a download using [Freshclam](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/freshclam.1.html).  The download appeared to proceed normally but when it finished it was not installed.  Freshclam then kept initiating further downloads with the same result until it timed out.  I used terminal commands to run freshclam (`sudo /etc/init.d/clamav-freshclam stop` then `sudo freshclam -v`)

I then uninstalled and then reinstalled [Clamav](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV) ([home page](http://www.clamav.net/)) and tried again with the same result. I used synaptic package manager for the uninstall and reinstall.

I then established where the virus signatures come from and was able to download *daily.cvd* to my downloads folder successfully, but have no idea where to move it and *main.cvd* to.

Any ideas as to the problem and solution, please?

Comment: 1) Did you install clamav using their own instructions http://www.clamav.net/documents/installation-on-debian-and-ubuntu-linux-distributions or from the Ubuntu repositories? 2) What commands did you use, or did you use Synaptec or the Software Center? 3) Did you install clamtk from their site or from the Ubuntu repositories? 4) What commands did you use, or did you use Synaptec or the Software Center? Please click [edit] to add that vto your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you.